# Two-class classification model with multi-type input data

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, r, keras

As a first introduction to machine learning and keras, I just finished reading Deep Learning with R by François Chollet with J.J. Allaire. I would like to extend the book's IMDB example of two-class classification to a multi-input version using functional API.

```
library(keras)

## Keras IMDB example

#load data
imdb <- dataset_imdb(num_words = 10000)
train_data <- imdb$train$x
train_labels <- imdb$train$y
test_data <- imdb$test$x
test_labels <- imdb$test$y

#Encoding the integer sequences into a binary matrix
vectorize_sequences <- function(sequences, dimension = 10000) {
results <- matrix(0, nrow = length(sequences), ncol = dimension)
for (i in 1:length(sequences))
results[i, sequences[[i]]] <- 1
results
}

x_train <- vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test <- vectorize_sequences(test_data)
y_train <- as.numeric(train_labels)
y_test <- as.numeric(test_labels)

#Defining the model
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(10000)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

#Compiling the model 
model %>% compile(
optimizer = "rmsprop",
loss = "binary_crossentropy",
metrics = c("accuracy")
)

#Training the model
history <- model %>% fit(
partial_x_train,
partial_y_train,
epochs = 20,
batch_size = 512,
validation_data = list(x_val, y_val)
)

#Defining the model using functional API
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_embedding(input_dim = 10000, output_dim = 8,
input_length = maxlen) %>%
layer_flatten() %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

So, I would like to create a similar model where we predict class `A` and `B` based on 1 continuous and 3 categorical input data. In this dummy example, `continuous1`, `categorical1` and `categorical2` are 1D tensors while similarly to the IMDB example, `categorical3` is a 2D tensor of shape `(samples, indices)` with length `num_index=20` and are one-hot encoded.

[image: Two-class classification multi-input model]

```
#Dummy data
dat <- data.frame(samples=c(rep(paste0("A_",1:9800)),rep(paste0("B_",9801:10000))))
dat$label <- c(rep("A",9800),rep("B",200))
dat$continuous1 <- c(rnorm(9800, 100, 45),rnorm(200, 0, 25)) #may    normalize to unit variance
dat$continuous1[dat$continuous1<0] <- 0
dat$categorical1 <- c(rep(1:100,98),rep(1:100,2))
dat$categorical2 <- c(rep(1:98,100),rep(99:100,100))

pool_A <- factor(1:15,levels=1:20)
pool_B <- factor(16:20,levels=1:20)
dat_categorical3 <- vector("list",10000)
names(dat_categorical3) <- c(as.character(dat[dat$label=="A",]$samples),as.character(dat[dat$label=="B",]$samples))
for(i in 1:9800){
  dat_categorical3[[i]] <- (as.numeric(table(sample(pool_A, 20, replace=T))) > 0) + 0L
}
for(i in 9801:10000){
  dat_categorical3[[i]] <- (as.numeric(table(sample(pool_B, 20, replace=T))) > 0) + 0L
}
```

As I've never built a Keras model before, I'm a bit confused on how to set up the layers representing the different data inputs using functional API. Any suggestions and feedback are highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are newly starting I would suggest you use C++ or Python, it will make you much more attractive as a candidate when searching for jobs.

Comment: I figure, for the purpose of this model, it shouldn't matter... same same different syntax.

Comment: Well if you have 2 different sources of features and you want them to go through different types of layers. Then build 2 separate models, then Concatenate their outputs, this merges the 2 models, then you can add more layers from there on towards the output. I wouldn't know the syntax to do that in R sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from a colleague, we came up with this:

```
set.seed(666)

#Dummy data
dat <- data.frame(samples=c(rep(paste0("A_",1:9800)),rep(paste0("B_",9801:10000))))
dat$label <- c(rep("A",9800),rep("B",200))
dat$continuous1 <- c(rnorm(9800, 100, 45),rnorm(200, 0, 25))
dat$continuous1[dat$continuous1<0] <- 0
dat$categorical1 <- c(rep(1:100,98),rep(1:100,2))
dat$categorical2 <- c(rep(1:98,100),rep(99:100,100))

pool_A <- factor(1:15,levels=1:20)
pool_B <- factor(16:20,levels=1:20)
dat_categorical3 <- vector("list",10000)
names(dat_categorical3) <- c(as.character(dat[dat$label=="A",]$samples),as.character(dat[dat$label=="B",]$samples))
for(i in 1:9800){
  dat_categorical3[[i]] <- (as.numeric(table(sample(pool_A, 20, replace=T))) > 0) + 0L
}
for(i in 9801:10000){
  dat_categorical3[[i]] <- (as.numeric(table(sample(pool_B, 20, replace=T))) > 0) + 0L
}
dat_categorical3_tensor <- do.call(rbind,dat_categorical3)


## Split data for training-validating-testing

# As we have much fewer Bs than As, each partition has to have a more or less equal number of Bs(?)
training_Bs <- sample(x=as.character(dat[dat$label=="B",]$samples), size=67, replace=F)
validating_Bs <- sample(x=setdiff(as.character(dat[dat$label=="B",]$samples),training_Bs), size=67, replace=F)
testing_Bs <- setdiff(as.character(dat[dat$label=="B",]$samples),c(training_Bs,validating_Bs))

# We also parition the data containing As equally, though this could probably be done in e.g., 80-10-10
training_As <- sample(x=as.character(dat[dat$label=="A",]$samples), size=3267, replace=F)
validating_As <- sample(x=setdiff(as.character(dat[dat$label=="A",]$samples),training_As), size=3267, replace=F)
testing_As <- setdiff(as.character(dat[dat$label=="A",]$samples),c(training_As,validating_As))

# Put together
training_dat <- dat[dat$samples %in% c(training_As,training_Bs),]
training_categorical3_tensor <- dat_categorical3_tensor[rownames(dat_categorical3_tensor) %in% c(training_As,training_Bs),]
training_labels <- ifelse(training_dat$label=="A",0,1)
training_dat2 <- as.matrix(training_dat[,c(3:5)]) #use this

validating_dat <- dat[dat$samples %in% c(validating_As,validating_Bs),]
validating_categorical3_tensor <- dat_categorical3_tensor[rownames(dat_categorical3_tensor) %in% c(validating_As,validating_Bs),]
validating_labels <- ifelse(validating_dat$label=="A",0,1) 
validating_dat2 <- as.matrix(validating_dat[,c(3:5)]) #use this

testing_dat <- dat[dat$samples %in% c(testing_As,testing_Bs),]
testing_categorical3_tensor <- dat_categorical3_tensor[rownames(dat_categorical3_tensor) %in% c(testing_As,testing_Bs),]
testing_labels <- ifelse(testing_dat$label=="A",0,1)
testing_dat2 <- as.matrix(testing_dat[,c(3:5)]) #use this


## Keras model

# Input layers
all_dat_input <- layer_input(shape = 3, dtype = 'float32', name = 'all_dat_input')
categorical3_indices_input <- layer_input(shape = 20, dtype = 'float32', name = 'categorical3_input')
input_tensor <- c(all_dat_input, categorical3_indices_input)

# Output layers
all_dat_out <- all_dat_input %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5)

categorical3_indices_out <- categorical3_indices_input %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5)

output_tensor <- layer_concatenate(c(all_dat_out, categorical3_indices_out)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")

model <- keras_model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=output_tensor)

# Compile
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = "accuracy"
)

# Fit
history <- model %>% fit(
  x=list(training_dat2,training_categorical3_tensor),
  y=training_labels,
  batch_size=256,
  epochs=20,
  validation_data=list(list(validating_dat2,validating_categorical3_tensor),validating_labels)
)
```

[image]

```
# Compare with put aside testing data
results <- model %>% evaluate(list(testing_dat2,testing_categorical3_tensor),testing_labels)

results
$loss
[1] 0.0000001584833
$acc
[1] 1

# Using the trained network to generate predictions on new data
predictions <- model %>% predict(list(testing_dat2,testing_categorical3_tensor))

head(predictions[3267:3332])
[1] 0.9999921 0.9999992 0.9999999 0.9999996 0.9999999 0.9999542    
# the network correctly identifies Bs as Bs with a confidence between >99%

(Remember that this is dummy data!)
```

I'm currently looking into `feature importance` to see which data inputs contributed more than others to the prediction. [`lime`](https://github.com/thomasp85/lime) seems to be made for this!